# How to prevent scroll bar from pushing content of ScrollPane in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, scrollbar, jscrollpane

I have growing content in `ScrollPane`. When content reaches bottom ages of `ScrollPane`, vertical scrollbar appears. At that time all content is being pushed to the left side by width of scrollbar. It's not much, but not pleasant for eye and ruins smooth user experience. Is there a way to prevent scrollbar from interfering with content? Maybe by positioning it outside of `ScrollPane` or specifying not to move content?

*With blue line I showed by how much content is getting pushed to the left:*
[image]

Comment: Post your FXML file.